# Next.js 13 Server Components - How tell to next.js that my component its not static without use fetch

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have a Server Component . Inside this component, I need to call the GitHub GraphQL API. For this, I used graphql-request, hence, I did not use the extended fetch from next.js that handles cache. However, next.js seems to be treating this component as static and, to make things worse, it can't understand something from this request (since it's not returning the value). I will omit the part of the function to make the request to GitHub because I was already using it without errors before.

```js
import getContributions from "@/services/github/getContrubutions";

const Contributions = async () => {
  const contributions = await getContributions();
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 4000))
  return (<>
    {JSON.stringify({'c':'d',  contributions, time: new Date()})}
  </>);
}

export default Contributions
```

In addition to the value being in cache or being static, it's not returning the API value. But when using `fetch` with some public JSON API like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 and setting it to have no cache `{cache: 'no-store'}`, this way the component seems to turn non-static and partial hydration starts to work... For example:

```
import getContributions from "@/services/github/getContrubutions";

const Contributions = async () => {
  const contributions = await getContributions();
  const foo = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', {cache: 'no-store'})
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 4000))
  const bee = await foo.json()
  return (<>
  {JSON.stringify({'c':'d', bee,  contributions, time: new Date()})}
  </>);
}

export default Contributions
```

By using fetch and 'no-store' for this endpoint, the component started being streamed indeed. But I need it to be so even without using fetch. I've drafted this text to post on StackOverflow but I need it to be in English.

Comment: Have you tried `force-dynamic`? https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#dynamic

Comment: This was one of the things I didn't remember and wanted to find. Thanks. But I tested it anyway, it was cached (using fetch and this exported const). Currently I stopped using that other lib for graphQL and I'm just using fetch. But my doubt still remains.